# How to fill a Listview with an Excel Sheet? (C#, Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, listview

Question is in the title.
I found no answer on the internet. The problem: I can't use an OleDbConnection because I have to send the file to someone else.

I am tired looking for an answer that may not exist, I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Here is my code, I am stuck at the filling:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string fname;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        fname = "";
        OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        fdlg.Title = "Excel File Dialog";
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        fdlg.Filter = "Excel .csv (*.csv)|*.csv";
        fdlg.FilterIndex = 1;
        fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fname = fdlg.FileName;
        }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xla.Visible = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Open(fname);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = ws.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                listView.Columns.Add(xlRange.Columns.Text);     //This line is not working
            }
        }

        xla.Quit();
        xla = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use csv it is simply a text file with one line for each row and columns are separated by some separator (e.g. a semicolon).

So you can read each line and split it by the separator. Then you can iterate over each line (= excel row) and inside over the split-array (= excel column/cell).

If it is the first row you should add a column for each row-entry to the list view. Then for each iterated entry you add an item to the current column. You can access the column via the index you use in the inner iteration.

To give a complete working solution:

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    fdlg.Title = "Excel File Dialog";
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
    fdlg.Filter = "Excel .csv (*.csv)|*.csv";
    fdlg.FilterIndex = 1;
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fdlg.FileName);
        int rowCount = lines.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            // split the row into cell values
            var cells = lines[i].Split(';');

            if (i == 0) // first row -> create column headers
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cells.Length; j++)
                {
                    listView.Columns.Add(cells[j]);
                }
            }
            else // not first row -> add values
            {
                // list view is organized as rows -> create a new row and add first item
                var newListViewRow = listView.Items.Add(cells[0]);

                // then add the rest of the values as subitems to the listview row
                for (int j = 1; j < cells.Length; j++)
                {
                    newListViewRow.SubItems.Add(cells[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Better move the code to Load event handler.
- Ensure that the property `View` of the list view is set to `Details`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following to read the data into a big object

object[,] values = (object[,])xlRange.Value2;

and access it with:
string nextVal = values[iRow, iCol] as string;